# Will @Transactional roolback when HTTP response times out?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a spring-boot REST application. Given a `RestController` method annotated with `@Transactional`, when the server processes the request and returns a valid response to the client. However the client fails to receive the response due to a request time out (example: poor internet connectivity).

What happens to the transaction? Is it committed or is it rolledback?

Is there a way to rollback the transaction in this scenario?

Example:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/orders")
@Transactional
public String saveOrderInTransaction(@RequestBody Order order) {
   // Business logic
   return "Order saved";
}
```

I am assuming that the `@Transactional` commits when `saveOrderInTransaction()` returns. Later the servlet container (Tomcat) writes to the protocol which is the *3: Server : Write* in the diagram below.

If that is correct, then I am assuming that the client may receive a request timeout and not be aware that the server processed its request. Are my assumptions correct? Is there a way to commit only when the client ack the response?

Please send me references with your answers.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to do that... if you think that your requests are going to take that long, you could create a transaction table? Then when the controller receives the request, it creates a transaction id and sends that back to the client immediately, and then asynchronously processes the request and updates that transaction table with the results.. the client then querys the transaction table periodically to see the status/results

Comment: Correct. That is a possible solution, it would look like a two-phase commit. As you pointed out that will require implementation on the server and client side which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Many, many, many moons ago I had to do something like this, and the solution was to have a filter that started the transaction (By the way, your code is not correct, as you cannot use *@Transactional* in rest controllers with spring, they don't do anything). The filter then checked at the end if the connection was still opened and just then would commit the transaction. There was still a very short time when things could go wrong, but it was an accepted risk.

Comment: @Augusto, thanks for the heads up, I keep forgeting the whole AOP shenanigans. I see what you mean. A filter looking at the ServletResponse.isCommited() is probably the best we can get.